# Vue.js unit test testing a component , got props type error

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I am trying to test an audio player ( start , pause, stop , mute, position, download events)

```
export default {
  name: "audioPlayer",
  props: {
    file: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    autoPlay: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
```

In my test specs, I set the file props as follwoing

```
  const file = new File(["../../src/assets/audio/ultimo_desejo.mp3"], "ultimo_desejo", { type: "audio/mp3"});
  const ended = jest.fn();
```

But when I run the test , I get an erro :

console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:589
    [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "file". Expected Object, got File.

```
found in

---> <AudioPlayer>
       <Root>
```

How should I set my file property ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `type` field of the `file` prop to `File`:

```
props: {
  file: {
    type: File,
    default: null
  },
}
```

Then, you could pass a new `File` in the `file` prop:

```js
it('takes a file prop', () => {
  const file = new File(['foo'], 'foo.txt');
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyFoo, {
    propsData: { file }
  });
  expect(wrapper.vm.file).toBeTruthy();
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/543oprxx2n?module=src/components/HelloWorld.spec.js)

Comment: thanks ...   but I am fighting with the url ... where should I store the foo file ?  (  if I store it in src/assets/audio/foo.mp3 ... which url ? )